# "Is there a word for a product used for killing mice?"

Tags: single-word-requests

A building in a nearby neighbourhood seems to be infested with mice.  A TV-News reporter was interviewing one of the janitors who said: "We tried to get rid of them but I don't think we used the right insecticide".   Hey, wait, mice are not insects.  I don't think we could use "insecticide" here, or could we?  Is there a word or compound-word for a substance that kills mice?  I thought of "pesticide" but I'm not sure it works in a domestic rather than in an agricultural context.

Comment: Try *muricide* perhaps?

Comment: @Robusto  I've found [muricidal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/muricidal) as "possessing the muricide instinct; inclined to kill mice"  It seems to be the instinct to kill mice, not the product.

Comment: I still think it applies. You're applying one aspect of the adverb form to the entire word.

Comment: @Robusto Well, if you still say so... you must be right. :-)

Comment: It is the most specific term I can think of. @chasly's "rodenticide" is undoubtedly a lot more common, but includes other rodents.

Comment: "Rodent control" is used euphemistically to include traps and poisons to deal with a rodent infestation.

Comment: Correct terminology and intended usage aside, most insecticide would probably suffice as rodenticide.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard - can you back that up with actual science? For example a suitable flea killer can be used on pet rats without killing them.

Comment: A *felid*. Ideally one of the recently domesticated crossbreeds of the silvestris species.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Rodenticides and biocides legislation
>
> This page explains how rodenticides (chemicals used to control rodents
>   such as rats and mice) are affected by biocides legislation. It is
>   intended to help suppliers wishing to market rodenticide products in
>   the UK, and people who use rodenticides, such as pest controllers
>
> [Health and Safety Executive (UK)](http://www.hse.gov.uk/biocides/eu-bpr/rodenticides.htm)

---

> Definition of RODENTICIDE
>
> :  an agent that kills, repels, or controls rodents
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rodenticide)

Comment: +1. It's the technical/intellectual word for "*rat poison*".

Comment: Quite so, but does rat poison work for mice?

Comment: Rat and mice poisons are the same products. "Rat poison" has 530 000 occurences in Google, whilst "mice poison" only occurs 12 000 times.

Comment: This ngram is quite interesting --->  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rat+poison%2Cmouse+poison%2Crat+bait%2Cmouse+bait%2Crodenticide&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crat%20poison%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmouse%20poison%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crat%20bait%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmouse%20bait%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crodenticide%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Indeed: at first glance, one may think that the technical term is widely used and understood. But, it may be explained by the fact that books or internet sites don't use the same terminology than ordinary people.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard - (a) I saw it as a technical term rather than a matter for ordinary dictionaries (b) I wanted an example. However I don't want to advertise so I shall substitute a different example.

Comment: Actually, some rat poisons do not work on mice.  The most common rat poison is one that causes rats to bleed internally.  It's a relatively "safe" poison because most other animals (including people and mice) have a chemical in their bodies that blocks it's action.  To make it into a mouse poison another chemical is added to block the action blocker (but this of course makes the mouse poison more hazardous).

Comment: @HotLicks, Source, please?  The most popular rat poisons I know of are the [4-hydroxycoumarins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-Hydroxycoumarins), which are just as effective on humans and mice as they are on rats.

Comment: @Mark - The chemical is warfarin, one of the coumarins.  (Though apparently it's become less popular vs 20-30 years ago, in part because rats are becoming resistant to it.)  The effectiveness of the pure drug in rats is far greater than in mice or humans, due to a genetic quirk in rats.

Comment: There are a number of anticoagulant poisons. Warfarin was the first, but rodent populations have become resistant to it. Of the others, some are more effective on rats, others on mice Compare Diphacinone  and Chlorophacinone at the end of this web page: http://animalscience.ucdavis.edu/avian/pfs23.htm. But rats and mice also differ in the type of baits they will eat in sufficient quantity to kill them, independent of the poison dose. Incidentally, warfarin is used in controlled doses in human medicine, as a blood anticoagulant.

Answer (score 0):

***[Ratsbane](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ratsbane):***

> - rat poison.(Random House Dictionary)
> - rat poison, especially arsenic trioxide. (AHD)